# Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'HEAD'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically add some script in HEAD

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const scripts = parser.parseFromString("<script>console.log('hello world')</script><noscript>console.log('hello world')</noscript>", 'text/xml');
const doc = scripts.getRootNode();
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(doc);
```

This is the error I get `HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'HEAD'.`

Comment: The snippet in your question will throw a `SyntaxError`, nothing more.

Comment: @Andreas and after the syntax errors are fixed, it will still throw an error because this is not a valid XML document

Comment: @VLAZ Hence my VtC

Comment: The real issue is that if if you do parse this into HTML, then `doc` is a *full* document. With its own body and head and so on. It's essentially inseting `<html><head><head<body></body></html>` in the `head` section. As the error in the question points out, that's not possible. It's also isn't very subtle - you only need examine what `doc` is if you're not sure. So, instead of placing *the whole* document, you need to extract the head content and only use that.

Comment: @VLAZ interesting. Isn't doc.head.innerHTML also a string?

Comment: It is but I'm not sure why that matters. `innerHTML` just serialises the DOM contents.

Comment: @VLAZ I've did something like this `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].append((doc as any).head.innerHTML);` and the result is `<head>"<script>console.log('hello world')</script><noscript>console.log('hello world')</noscript>"</head>`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've did

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const scripts = parser.parseFromString("<script>console.log('hello world')</script><noscript>console.log('hello world')</noscript>", 'text/xml');
const doc = scripts.getRootNode();
(doc as any).head.childNodes.forEach(c => {
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(c);
});
```

If someone has a better answer, I'll gladly accept it